How to escape a dollar sign?
I asked a question about a study of behavioral economics, and mentioned some example amounts given to participants. I was surprised to notice that I couldn't type a dollar sign followed by an amount of money, as it got converted to a TeX expression. 
I wasn't aware that Cognitive Sciences has the TeX extension. But now I know it, how do I avoid it, so I can use the dollar sign to denote dollars, as opposed to formulae? 

I fixed up your question.  You just need to escape the dollar sign with a backslash \, so e.g., 

\$ 200,000  


Thank you - I should have tried the intuitive option instead of looking around for the TFM and getting frustrating for not finding it.

@rumtscho It's all good, no big deal.  Welcome to the site! :)
